# psycopg2 use column names instead of column number to get row data

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

So currently when I execute SELECT query and retrieve data I have to get results like this:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="admin",
                              password="admin",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              database="postgres_db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
users = cursor.fetchall() 

for row in users:
    print(row[0])
    print(row[1])
    print(row[2])
```

What I want to do is, use column names instead of integers, like this:

```
for row in users:
    print(row["id"])
    print(row["first_name"])
    print(row["last_name"])
```

Is this possible, and if it is, then how to do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use RealDictCursor, then you can access the results like a dictionary:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="...",
                              password="...",
                              host="...",
                              port="...",
                              database="...",
                              cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
users = cursor.fetchall()

print(users)
print(users[0]['user'])
```

Output:

```
[RealDictRow([('user', 'dbAdmin')])]
dbAdmin
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `RealDictCursor` will raise a `KeyError` if an integer index is passed.  `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor` accepts both string (column name) keys and integer indexes.

Answer (score 6):

no need to call fetchall() method, the psycopg2 cursor is an iterable object you can directly do:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

for buff in cursor:
    row = {}
    c = 0
    for col in cursor.description:
        row.update({str(col[0]): buff[c]})
        c += 1

    print(row["id"])
    print(row["first_name"])
    print(row["last_name"])
```

Comment: Didn't know that. But this still doesn't answer my question because when I try to use `string` instead of an `integer` to get the `row` value it throws and exception.

Comment: @duško-mirković Yep my bad, I wrote my answer too fast and forgot the code part to manage the cursor result as a dict. I edited my answer.